# C#: Loop through unread email items in specific Outlook mailbox

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am very new to Outlook programming.

I have a mailbox let's say "ImportantMail" in my Outlook.

I am developing a windows form application which should find all the unread emails in that mailbox and loop through them accessing subject, sender & content.

Is there some simple method to achieve this?

I've tried following multiple tutorials I found, but it's too confusing for a fresher like me...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I was working backwards in my case because I was moving mail items, so to make that work you need to go in reverse, however.. this really isnt a difficult thing to work out - I accounted for meeting requests etc..

```
for (int t = objFolder.Items.Count; t >= 1; t--)
{
    try
    {
        if (!(objFolder.Items[t] is MailItem)) continue;
        MailItem m = objFolder.Items[t];
        if (m.Unread) { do_stuff(); }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Do not ever loop through all items in a folder, this is extremely inefficient. Use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict

Comment: Using multiple dot notation (objFolder.Items.Count and objFolder.Items[t] which is equivalent to objFolder.Items.Item(t))) is another problem.

Comment: In my case, i was actually having to read all mails and then move them, so this was efficient for ehat i was doing. Hence its in my answer. I didnt claim it was the most efficient, just a way of doing

Comment: Your loop above does have a condition on the Unread property. For a typical Inbox folder, it would evaluate to one percent or less of the total number of messages. Ignoring 99% of messages in a folder is pretty inefficient.

Comment: True, but as explained this actually came out of my app and explained you can loop in reverse and move items, with added if unread do.. My app moves stuff when dealt with so this has never been an issue

Comment: Sorry to be nitpicky, but the original question was about processing only unread emails, not about moving all items in a folder. As such,  looping through **all** items in a folder is totally inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If ImportantMail mailbox is already in the current profile, retrieve that store from the `Application.Session.Stores` collection and call `Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`. If it is an Exchange delegate store that is not yet in the current profile, call `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` then `Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(..., olFolderInbox)`.

Read the MAPIFolder.Items property, then use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict with a query like `[Unread] = true`.